# How to create a trigger to send email with dynamic subject in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-chatter

I am trying to write a trigger to send email which dynamically adds subject.
as I am new to salesforce, please help for dynamically adding subject.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for ur response.

Comment: I have done using Dynamic SOQl.